# Optimized implementations of the Random Forest algorithm

Tags: random-forest, algorithms, model-evaluation

I have noticed that there are a few implementations of random forest such as ALGLIB, Waffles and some R packages like `randomForest`.  Can anybody tell me whether these libraries are highly optimized?  Are they basically equivalent to the random forests as detailed in [The Elements of Statistical Learning](http://statweb.stanford.edu/~tibs/ElemStatLearn/) or have a lot of extra tricks been added?

I hope this question is specific enough.  As an illustration of the type of answer I am looking for, if somebody asked me whether the linear algebra package BLAS was highly optimized, I would say it was extremely highly optimized and mostly not worth trying to improve upon except in very specialized applications.

Comment: Random Jungle can run on many servers in a parallel manner. See: Schwarz, et al (2010). On safari to Random Jungle: a fast implementation of Random Forests for high-dimensional data. *Bioinformatics, 26*, 14, pp 1752–8, https://doi.org/10.1093/bioinformatics/btq257. code: [1](https://sourceforge.net/p/randomjungle/code/HEAD/tree/trunk/); [2](https://github.com/gitpan/RandomJungle); [3](https://github.com/insilico/randomjungle); [4](https://github.com/texane/randomjungle).

Answer (score 33, accepted):

(Updated 6 IX 2015 with suggestions from comments, also made CW)

There are two new, nice packages available for R which are pretty well optimised for a certain conditions:

- [ranger](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ranger/index.html) -- C++, R package, optimised for $p>>n$ problems, parallel, special treatment of GWAS data.
- [Arborist](https://github.com/suiji/Arborist) -- C++, R and Python bindings, optimised for large-$n$ problems, apparently plans for GPGPU.

Other RF implementations:

- [The Original One](http://www.stat.berkeley.edu/%7Ebreiman/RandomForests/cc_home.htm)  -- standalone Fortran code, not parallel, pretty hard to use.
- [randomForest](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/randomForest/index.html) -- C, R package, probably the most popular, not parallel, actually quite fast when compared on a single-core speed basis, especially for small data.
- [randomForestSRC](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/randomForestSRC/index.html) -- C, R package, clone of randomForest supporting parallel processing and survival problems.
- [party](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/party/index.html) -- C, R package, quite slow, but designed as a plane for experimenting with RF.
- [bigrf](https://github.com/aloysius-lim/bigrf) -- C+/R, R package, built to work on *big data* within [bigmemory framework](http://bigmemory.org/); quite far from being complete.
- [scikit learn Ensemble forest](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/ensemble.html#forest) -- Python, part of scikit-learn framework, parallel, implements many variants of RF.
- [milk](https://pythonhosted.org/milk/)'s RF -- Python, part of milk framework.
- [so-called WEKA rf](http://code.google.com/p/fast-random-forest/) -- Java/WEKA, parallel.
- [ALGLIB](http://www.alglib.net/)
- [rt-rank](https://sites.google.com/site/rtranking/home) -- abandoned?

[Ranger paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/1508.04409) has some speed/memory comparisons, but there is no thorough benchmark.

Comment: One can now add [sklearn.ensemble](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/ensemble.html) from the Python scikit-learn toolbox.

Comment: Milk in Python also has a Random Forest implementation.

Comment: Random Jungle has been superseded by Ranger. I've tried the R ver (there is another C++ ver) and it is noticeably faster than randomForest (I didn't time it though). The author has done some testing in a separate paper (http://arxiv.org/abs/1508.04409).

Comment: isn't randomForest implemented in FORTRAN ?

Answer (score 14):

As far as I know, the R version of randomForest calls the same Fortran code as the original version.  Furthermore, it's trivial to parallelize the randomForest function. It's actually one of the examples provided in the [foreach documentation](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/foreach/vignettes/foreach.pdf).

```
library(foreach)
library(randomForest)
rf <- foreach(ntree = rep(250, 4), .combine = combine, .packages = "randomForest") %dopar% 
randomForest(x, y, ntree = ntree)
```

Given that random forests are embarrassingly parallel, the biggest optimization you can make is running them in parallel.  After that, I don't think there's any other low-hanging fruit in the algorithm, but I could be wrong.

The only issue is that you lose the out-of-bag error estimate in the combined forest, but there's probably a simple way to calculate it (I'd actually love to find out how to do this).

Comment: but combined forests lose some functionality - summaries of errors are not combined (or rather recalculated) and so one

Answer (score 7):

The [ELSII](http://www-stat.stanford.edu/~tibs/ElemStatLearn/) used [randomForest](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/randomForest/index.html) (see e.g., footnote 3 p.591), which is an R implementation of the Breiman and Cutler's [Fortran code](http://stat-www.berkeley.edu/users/breiman/RandomForests) from Salford. Andy Liaw's code is in C.

There's another implementation of RFs proposed in the [party](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/party/index.html) package (in C), which relies on R/Lapack, which has some dependencies on BLAS (see`/include/R_ext/Lapack.h` in your base R directory).

As far as bagging is concerned, it should not be too hard to parallelize it, but I'll let more specialized users answer on this aspect.

Answer (score 5):

The team behind randomJungle claims that is an order of magnitude faster than 
the R randomForest implementation and uses an order magnitude less memory.
A package for randomJungle is being developed for R but I can't get to build yet.

https://r-forge.r-project.org/projects/rjungler/

Comment: Not sure if this is still of interest to you after 4 years but the author(s) of randomJungle has superseded it with Ranger. I've tried the R ver and it is indeed noticeably faster than randomForest with some sample data (I didn't time it though).

Answer (score 3):

For the **Javascript** Implementation go through this demo.

If you are like a child who is hungry for a chocolate, here is your chocolate of random forest 
http://cs.stanford.edu/people/karpathy/svmjs/demo/demoforest.html